# List windows gui components using pywin32

Tags: python, pywin32

Thanks in advance. 
How can I list all the components like the buttons labels textboxs everything. I dont know if this is possible with pywin32. I am using python 3.5, windows 10 x64.

Comment: Do you mean all available *standard* Win32 components?

Comment: Incidentally, to reply to a specific person on SO type the '@' symbol to get a menu then select a name from it.

Comment: standard win32 components and also no standard.

Comment: What do you mean by _available_? As you know such controls are implemented in *.dll*s (_comctl32.dll_) and some other files as well. Also _all_ is another "heavy" term. Probably, a list of registered control classes could be get via *WinAPI*s or is public somewhere, and if you'd know how to get it, then problem solved as _pywin32_ is just a wrapper. But what is the problem that you're trying to solve, because this approach doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what items might be included in that class. If you have PythonWin, which is a good REPL for working with Python on Windows, you can get extensive lists of GUI components from its help files. For instance, you could select 'Python for Win32 Extensions Help' then 'Objects' under 'Pythonwin and win32ui' to see the list of available GUI objects in this category. By right-clicking within the list you'd get the HTML which you could process for a list.

I hope somebody has a better way!

Comment: But no Idea how to get no standard win32 components.

Comment: Is there any way to read the variables in memory for specific process

Comment: I think you mean *non-standard* components. Can you give me an example? As to your second point, you should a separate SO question where you show the details of what you have in mind. What kind of process? How was it started? Etc.

Comment: Maybe pywinauto is what you need? All you're describing is a GUI automation task, right?